# Consuming QnA and LUIS in a v4 bot

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

Documentation tells me I need CognitiveServices package to obtain support for consuming LUIS and QnA services. However, v4 uses the Core framework and https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices/ gives a warning that it requires 4.6

> warn : Package 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices 1.1.7' was
>   restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project
>   target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be
>   fully compatible with your project.

Are there dotnet core versions of the CognitiveServices packages, or it is LUIS and QnA support now somewhere else?

My interest in the CognitiveServices package is entirely driven by the need to consume LUIS and QnA services from a v4 bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Cognitive Service would you like to use? The package you mentioned was done for v3 bots.

For example, some of the `Cognitive Services` are included in the `Bot Builder SDK librairies`:

- LUIS: https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS
- QnA Maker: https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA

These librairies are used to consume the services.

Otherwise, there are also other official NuGet packages, have a look to [`Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices...`](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices) packages, targeting .Net Standard or .Net Framework:

- [`Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.ContentModerator`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.ContentModerator/)
- [`Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision/)
- [`Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.TextAnalytics`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.TextAnalytics/2.8.0-preview)
- etc.

Comment: Your first para is right on point. My interest in CogServices is entirely driven by the need to consume LUIS and QnA services. I will put this plus supporting info into the question.

Comment: It would appear that the key is to read _all_ of the error message. I originally _tried_ to add the packages you list and they threw errors so I moved on looking for another answer without reading the details. The trick is to edit the csproj and bump all the versions to suit (4.2.2 at time of comment). It may help others if you fold this into your answer.

Comment: Or doing a Nuget package upgrade of your project?

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's an easy single command Nuget package upgrade. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41080749/how-do-i-update-all-nuget-packages-at-once-with-the-dotnet-cli

Comment: Was talking about doing it in an IDE like Visual Studi