# Updating net5.0 .csproj to net6.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

my current .csproj has the following project stats:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-XYZ</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I also have several entries in my `ItemGroup` indicating `"Version="5.0.10"`.

Since I am upgrading, I uninstalled old runtimes/frameworks and

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

shows:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Manually changing the project entries was not successful.

Is there a way to point this project to the new SDK installation?

Comment: What version did you update to? dotnet --list-runtimes shows which .NET runtimes are installed on the computer, but you don't have .net5 information.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Runtime != SDK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Visual Studio

If you are using Visual Studio, all you need to do is:
Right-click on your project in `solution explorer`, Properties > Application > Target Framework, then choose `.NET 6.0`. (Currently, this works only in VS 2022)

To update all packages you have installed:
Right-click on your project in `solution explorer`, `Manage NuGet packages...` >  `Update` Tab > Check `Select all packages` > click on `Update` button.

#### Manually

All you need to do is change the `.csproj` file like:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

More info [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 5.0 to 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code)

To update all packages you have installed, use this `PowerShell` script:

```
$regex = 'PackageReference Include="([^"]*)" Version="([^"]*)"'

ForEach ($file in get-childitem . -recurse | where {$_.extension -like "*proj"})
{
    $packages = Get-Content $file.FullName |
        select-string -pattern $regex -AllMatches | 
        ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} | 
        ForEach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value.ToString()}| 
        sort -Unique
    
    ForEach ($package in $packages)
    {
        write-host "Update $file package :$package"  -foreground 'magenta'
        $fullName = $file.FullName
        iex "dotnet add $fullName package $package"
    }
}
```

Base on [Rolf Wessels's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779627/11971428).

But I recommend using the [dotnet-outdated](https://github.com/dotnet-outdated/dotnet-outdated) tool.